# VBA to login in zerodha account and then download and again upload live data for buy and sell signal

Tags: excel, vba, screen-scraping

I want my VBA to:

1. Login into [Zerodha](https://zerodha.com/) kite account.
2. Integrate API.
3. Then download the live data from there and after analysing the data, it should upload data for buy or sell option.

I tried to log on to Zerodha account, but it is just refusing my request, so I can't do anything.

```
Sub Test()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate ("https://https://kite.zerodha.com/" & ActiveCell)
    Do
        If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
            ie.Visible = False
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
    ie.Document.Forms(0).all("User").Value = "aaa"
    ie.Document.Forms(0).all("Password").Value = "bbbb"
    ie.Document.Forms(0).submit

End Sub
```

I want that I should be able to integrate zerodha API then download the live data from there in I2 and after certain calculation I want the price of J2 to be uploaded for buy or sell signal.

Comment: if they have an API surely they don't expect you to use browser automation. Have you checked the documentation? Or does step 2 relate to something else unknown to us?

Comment: actually i dont know the whole process. I am having api key but dont know how to download and upload data to the website

Comment: Same question: [Importing data using Zerodha API in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790093/importing-data-using-zerodha-api-in-excel-vba). Please don't post the same question several times.